# updating a field of sql table from a variable

Tags: mysql

how can i update a field of sql table from a variable not a string?
my table name is variabless.this table contains 2 columns : (name & value)
i have the following line in my code:

```
c.execute("UPDATE variabless SET value=fasele WHERE name='fas'")
```

the point is **fasele** is a global variable...i think my syntax about inserting a variable(not fixed string) in a field of sql table is not correct (when using from **update** command)
i get the following error

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/start/gui/jus-submeno-image-refreshh.py", line 963, in saving4
    c.execute("UPDATE variabless SET value=fasele WHERE name='fas'")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: fasele
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks slightly malformed. I think it'll work if you put quotes around 'fasele'. So: `c.execute("UPDATE variabless SET value='" + str(fasele) + "' WHERE name='fas'")`

Comment: i tried it...i didn't get the error...but it don't update **value**

Comment: Even when you enter the query directly into mysql without using python? MySql usually returns some data as to what happened (e.g. "1 row modified").

P.s. I changed my answer slightly since you said fasele is a variable.

Comment: i used new command..but i got the following error.'Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/start/gui/jus-submeno-image-refreshh.py", line 964, in saving4
    c.execute("UPDATE variabless SET value='"+fasele+"' WHERE name='fas'")
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: Alright now we're getting close. This problem is caused because the integer needs to be converted to a string. I edited my answer to include the conversion of `fasele` from integer to string by using `str()`. Does it work now?

Comment: i didn't get error...but it don't update the **value**

Comment: Then I'd recommend you to try to enter the query directly into mysql, replacing `" + str(fasele) + "` with a value. Does it work?
What if you you select all rows with name 'fas' (`SELECT * FROM variabless WHERE name='fas'`)?

Comment: when i replace a value instead " + str(fasele) + "...'c.execute("UPDATE variabless SET value='5' WHERE name='fas'")'..and then the command 'self.cur.execute("SELECT value FROM variabless WHERE name='fas'")' ...i get '[('fas', 30)]
'...why?????????